# Unable to initialize object from controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller, initialization

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/ws4f1ktk/) looks like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.controller = angular.('testAppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.vehicle = {
        type: 'car',
        color: 'red'
    };
    $scope.vehicleDetail() = function () {
        return "Vehicle type : " + vehicle.type + ", "
        vehicle.color;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testAppCtrl">

<h1>
AngularJS object ng-init powered by controller example
</h1>

Type: <input ng-model='vehicle.type' />
<br/>

Color: <input ng-model='vehicle.color'/>

Vehicle details : {{vehicleDetail()}}

</div>
```

I was trying to initialize objects from inside controller using function, *instead of using ng-init*.

**Problem**

> Why are the values not getting printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code should correct like below,

this is how you need to define the controller, not like `app.controller = angular.('testAppCtrl', function ($scope) {`.

```
app.controller('testAppCtrl',function($scope)...
```

this is how you need to return the value in function `vehicleDetail`, In your return case you can't access `vehicle` properties like `vehicle.color`, you need to access it like `$scope.vehicle.color` since `vehicle` is in scope. and this `$scope.vehicleDetail() = function () {..` is wrong it should be corrected as `$scope.vehicleDetail = function () {..`

```
$scope.vehicleDetail = function()
{
    return "Vehicle type : " + $scope.vehicle.type + ", "+ $scope.vehicle.color;
};
```

here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1x025f5p/)

Comment: :) cheerz glad to help you